# Are there applications to program in binary?

Tags: assembly, binary

There are some who claim they can program in binary. Is it possible to program in binary on a modern system in today's world? Obviously there isn't much benefit to programming in binary. The question I'm asking is whether or not it is actually possible.

Back in the early days of computing there were punch cards for that sort of thing. The punched holes translated to electrical signals. Punch cards were a way to store commands (a type of data, you could say) onto a medium. We have media today that we can store data onto, such as tapes, floppy discs, CDs, DVDs, hard drives and more. The only problem: those things don't have "holes" with which we could indicate a "0" or a "1" in binary. They have other ways of storing data that isn't as easy to access by human beings. We can't simply "cut out" commands with today's media.

With all that said, are there applications with which a person could type the ASCII character "1" or "0" and have it actually translate into the electrical signals 1 or 0 (respectively)? Is programming in binary in this day and age possible?

Comment: Even if one would program in "binary" these days, it would use hexadecimal, not 0s and 1s.

Comment: Why would you do that? Assembly level is enough..

Comment: Real programmers use copy con > t.exe :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write an EXE file using only a hex editor. That would be programming in binary - you won't even be using assembly.

You could even skip the complexities of the EXE file structure by "cheating" a little, and writing a C program with a byte-array containing your "binary-programming" efforts, and then executing that pointer.

```
const unsigned char *binary_program = {
    // Your binary programming goes here.
    0xaa, 0xbb, 0xff,
};

typedef void (*func_type)(); 


int main() {
    func_type func = (func_type) binary_program;
    func();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: A COM file would be more traditional.

Comment: Is a COM file a first class citizen in a modern 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? In any event, I was just giving an example. You could say write an ELF file for Linux or something else for ARM.

Comment: No, it's not a first-class citizen, and you could indeed write any of those with a hex editor. I guess I was just saying that a COM file would be a lot easier to write if one were to begin trying to write an application with only a hex editor since it's basically all code with no headers or imposed structuring.

Comment: One way would be to cheat a little, and create a C program, where you have a pointer to a char-array containing your "binary-programming" efforts, and then executing that pointer. Then the C compiler will take care of all the EXE file structure.

Comment: Another way to cheat a little would be to use an assembler with an `incbin` or similar directive in a section. It'll include the raw contents of the file into the EXE but do all the headers and such for you.

Comment: A block of memory in which `binary_program` resides must be executable (PAGE_EXECUTE flag on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Programming in binary would be silly because it would be amazingly slow

You would need to use a lookup table in a book to remember all your commands, which would be stored as hex bytes by the pooter

Assembly automatically does all this for you, hugely simplifying the process

you write: cmp ecx,edx

the hex is 3B CA

the binary is?

Then you've got to "read" columns of binary for any debugging to happen...

00001000001110001000111100000101

00000111000100011110000010100110

etc

good luck to anyone taking this route, lol